# Converting foreign characters to normal

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have an international photo website. When the office uploads photos that have come from abroad, the captions and headlines sometimes have foreign characters, such as:

```
1. François Hollande
2. ValŽrie Trierweiler
```

And these get stored in the database (MySQL – latin1_swedish_ci), as-is. Now, when it comes to searching for Francois, without the French characters, in plain English, those particular photos do not display.

Now this isn't just a problem with French characters – it's other countries too. How is this possible, before I submit to my database, to convert these foreign characters to normal ones, like:

1. Francois Hollande

Comment: There is a PHP module named translit http://pecl.php.net/package/translit, perhaps you can get inspiration from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using `Adodb.Stream` with `ascii` charset. Here is an example:

```
With Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
    .Charset = "ascii"
    .Open
    .WriteText "François Hollande ValŽrie Trierweiler ÖÇŞİĞÜöçşığü ôûõòùìñ"
    .Position = 0
    Response.Write .ReadText
End With
```

Above script must print `Francois Hollande ValZrie Trierweiler OCSIGUocsigu ouoouin` exactly.

Answer (score 1):

And like this it can be a function

```
Function unaccent(strg)
    With Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
    .Charset = "ascii"
    .Open
    .WriteText strg
    .Position = 0
    unaccent = .ReadText
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net) will most probably cover your case.

You don't need an external library, and you can check for conformance using a numerous of methods, using regexes being my personal preference for not too large strings.